# Does the Orbital energy of a satellite in an elliptical orbit depend on the semi-major axis of the orbit?

Tags: communication-satellite, energy, orbital, axis

I am learning about Space exploration and I have the following question:

Does the Orbital energy of a satellite in an elliptical orbit depend on the semi-major axis of the orbit?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy


It appears the answer is yes; the SMA is a major factor, along with the masses of the two objects.

Comment: You should be doing some research on your own prior to asking a question. For this question, it is very easy to find the answer on the internet.

Comment: And not just for elliptical orbits, but for all Keplerian-Newtonian orbits and trajectories under the two-body approximation.

Comment: thank you! will do! sometimes i do not find the answer or it is not as obvious to me unfortunately, but this one is truly easy and the answer is indeed yes! Thank you for your help thus far!